# how can i do the comparison operator for every two values?

Tags: python

so i need to compare the two integers values by using greater than in a list.
for instance,

I have a list that looks like this :

```
elias 90
jo 100 
elias 93
jo 73
```

and I need to compare every two values and

print the name of the person with greater scores

so my expected result will be :

```
jo
elias
```

this is what I have so far. i know it's wrong because it doesn't calculate every two values.
I'm stuck and don't know how to proceed. help

```
for i in range(len(['total_votes'])):
           previous_element= df['total_votes'][i-1]
           if i > 0:
                print("Donald Trump")
           else:
                print("Joe Biden")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use striding subscripts to access even and odd entries in the list. combine them using the zip function and perform the selection in a list comprehension:

```
aList = [ ('elias',90), ('jo',100), ('elias',93), ('jo',73) ]

winners = [ name1 if score1>score2 else name2
            for (name1,score1),(name2,score2) in zip(aList[::2],aList[1::2]) ]

print(winners) # ['jo', 'elias']
```